# User input Turtle and/or Pygame

Tags: python, python-turtle

Is there anyway to get a user input within the user interface in Python (pygame OR turtle). I'm relatively new to Python and was wondering how to get this input through the INTERFACE rather than the terminal.

Comment: read about tkinter and canvas using python

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code that blits input to the screen using pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def name():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 360))
    name = ""
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
    while True:
       for evt in pygame.event.get():
          if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
               if evt.unicode.isalpha():
                  name += evt.unicode
               elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                  name = name[:-1]
               elif evt.key == K_RETURN:
                  name = ""
          elif evt.type == QUIT:
              return
       screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
       block = font.render(name, True, (255, 255, 255))
       rect = block.get_rect()
       rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
       screen.blit(block, rect)
       pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
name()
pygame.quit()
```

Here is the gist version if you need it [git](https://gist.github.com/ohsqueezy/4428513)